# SQLite .net provider & "prepare statement" functionality

Tags: c#, sqlite, dapper

**PREFACE**

One can find a description of the SQLite's *"Prepared Statement"* functionality [here](https://sqlite.org/c3ref/stmt.html).

SQLite command *(SQLite provider for .NET)* has a method "Prepare" with the following description:

> Summary:
>       Does nothing. Commands are prepared as they are executed
>       the first time, and kept in prepared state afterwards.

**QUESTIONS**

1. In general, does SQLite's ***Prepared Statement*** functionality improve overall performance of the query, which is executed over and over again?
2. Where the prepared statements are kept? How can I be sure that these prepared statements are in fact being used?
3. How can I be sure that Dapper is utilizing these statements? (*In my case, I use Dapper to run the same query several hundred times. The query fetches 10k results in each call, based on passed parameters*).

**EDIT:**

Just've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13505099/1151392), which partially answers my question. Non the less, if I need to build the DbCommand my self and then keep it somewhere, how can I use the command with Dapper?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is entirely true to say that Dapper does not currently call `Prepare()`.

You can read an extended explanation [here](http://blog.marcgravell.com/2017/12/dapper-prepared-statements-and-car-tyres.html?m=1#what-does-is-mean-to-prepare-a-statement)

Long story short the main reason is: Dapper really, really doesn't want to store your connections, because it is designed with high concurrency in mind, and typically work in scenarios where the DbConnection is short-lived

Comment: Well, that makes sense. Maybe plain ADO.net will work for me in this specific scenario. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. This is the best explanation I've read so far about the benefits and downsides of the Prepare() statement in ADO.NET.